# Creating a "kill current session" shortcut in Tmux

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to create a shortcut in Tmux which would kill current session? Typing "kill-session -t mysession" is not very convenient

I imagine something like

`bind X kill-session -t $currentsesion`

what I do not understand how to let bind know which session is current.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After playing around I found that I can make following shorcut which behaves the way I want:

- Kills current session
- Leaves all other sessions intact

`bind X confirm-before "kill-session -t ''"`

This solution seems to work but also looks like a hack. I hope there is
a better way to do this.

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/918610/creating-a-kill-current-session-shortcut-in-tmux/918934#comment1239294_918934), omitting the `-t` parameter will cause `tmux` to automatically use the current session so the code could also be shortened to:

`bind X confirm-before kill-session`

Comment: The empty string is certainly a valid way of spelling “the current session” as a *target-session*, but you can also just leave out the `-t` (and its argument): “the current session” is the default *target-session* if `-t` is not supplied. So just this should work: `bind X confirm-before kill-session`

Answer (score 1):

You can define shortcuts for `tmux` by editing `~/.tmux.conf`, and supplying a suitable `bind-key` line.  The [manual page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1) shows some examples.

For additional reading:

- *[Overriding tmux shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842672/overriding-tmux-shortcuts)*
- *[A tmux Primer](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tmux/)*
- *[screen to tmux: A Humble Quick-start Guide](https://myhumblecorner.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/screen-to-tmux-a-humble-quick-start-guide/)*

Comment: I understand how to create shortcuts, but I do not know how to refer to the current session